# CURL works only as root

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, curl

I'm on an Ubuntu 10.04 installation and somehow curl stopped working with my user.
I always receive: curl: (7) couldn't connect to host. It only works as root.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What about wget? Just curious.

Comment: wget, that worked!

Comment: Is `curl` an alias of shell function for one of the user, or do you have more than one version installed with the users reaching different versions because of different `PATH` settings (what does `type curl` say)?

Comment: I checked it and for both user it's curl is /usr/bin/curl.

Comment: Do you have SELinux or AppArmor active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the [`curl google.com`strace log](http://pastebin.com/bmFeK6Xn) and the key line is surely 409:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9999), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
```

If I (for the testing) launch `curl http://localhost:1357`, I get in the strace:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1357), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
```

So, by some weird reason instead of `google.com` curl tries to connect to `localhost:9999`.

Can you post:

- `/etc/hosts`
- `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `/etc/host.conf`
- `/etc/gai.conf`
- output of `ldd /usr/bin/curl`
- output of `env`

Comment: Also the contents of `/etc/host.conf` and `/etc/gai.conf` (at least if there are non-comment lines).

Comment: @Gilles: thanks, added them. just never seen these files anywhere, so they missed my eye...

Comment: Thanks for your hint with the output of env!
A network proxy were enabled.
The ALL_PROXY and all_proxy were set. Finally after disabling the proxy everything works.

Comment: I'd never seen them either, but the `# Configuration for getaddrinfo` at the top of `/etc/gai.conf` caught my eye. And line 409 is a replay of 386, which presumably follows a `getaddrinfo` call.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one user is using a proxy and the other one isn't. See if either your user or root has the `http_proxy` or `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable defined.

Also see if root has a `.curlrc` file that contains an option that makes it work, or if your user has a `.curlrc` that makes it not work.

Comment: the environment variable isn't set for both user and a .curlrc file also doesn't seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that maybe some library that curl needs is now only accessible by root for whatever reason.  A couple of things you could try:

```
sudo apt-get purge curl libcurl3
sudo apt-get install curl
```

then, if that doesn't fix it:

```
strace curl http://site.com/file.txt &> curl.log
```

and post the output on pastebin.com or something for us.

Comment: The re-installation didn't helped.
But here is the output of strace curl http://www.google.com
http://pastebin.com/bmFeK6Xn